# Not getting the total from another sheet after hyperlink is read because of multiple hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm running few macros to count the words, characters, paragraphs and others of the text in column B. However some of the text in column B are hyperlinks.

The Output Sheet:
[image: Output Sheet]

Right now, I have the code (below) that is opening the hyperlink and crawling the website data back to Excel on a different sheet (image 02).

[image: After Display_Stylometric_Scores_URL runs]

At the data sheet, it is counting how many words, characters, paragraphs and others of the text and then sum everything together (first, by column; then by words, characters, paragraphs, and etc.) and transfer the values to the Output sheet.

[image: Totals have been added, would like those totals, go to the Output sheet in the respective columns]

However, the For loop in the Display_Stylometric_Scores_Text that reads the hyperlinks in column B in the Output sheet, it will read and process all the hyperlinks but only gave me the correctly transferred value of the very last hyperlink.

Not all results are transferred correctly:
[image: Result to Output]

I am using an variable called textRow to keep track of which row of the text, it is reading. I have tried putting textRow = textRow + 1 into the For loop, hoping it will read the first hyperlink and transfer the totals back to the Output sheet but when I do, it does not process correctly for any of the hyperlinks. In this example, the first hyperlink is in row 24 so textRow = 24.

I guess my question is: how can I still use the For loop to read the hyperlinks row by row (updating textRow) and will only go to the next row or next hyperlink after it has outputted the correct totals from the previous hyperlink?

Code included:

```
Sub Display_Stylometric_Scores_Text()
Dim Words As String
Dim Characters As String
Dim Paragraphs As String
Dim Sentences As String
Dim Sentences_per_paragraph As String
Dim Words_per_sentence As String
Dim Characters_per_word As String
Dim Ratio_of_passive_sentences As String
Dim Flesch_Reading_Ease_score As String
Dim Flesch_Kincaid_Grade_Level_score As String
Dim Coleman_Liau_Readability_Score As String
Dim Ampersands As Long
Dim Exclamations As Long

Dim ActiveDocument As Object
Dim RS As Object
Dim link As Hyperlink
Dim path As String

textRow = 24

path = Dir("C:\Users\Jeannette\Desktop\*.txt")

Set ActiveDocument = CreateObject("Word.Document")

Do While Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 1) <> ""

    textValue = Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 2).Value
    ActiveDocument.Content = textValue

    Set RS = ActiveDocument.Content.ReadabilityStatistics

   For Each link In Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 2).Hyperlinks
        activeWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & textValue, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "Text From URL"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        ActiveSheet.Activate

        Call Display_Stylometric_Scores_URL

        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 4).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 5).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 6).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 7).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 7).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 8).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 8).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 9).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 9).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 10).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 11).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 11).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 12).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 12).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 13).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 13).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 14).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 14).Value
        Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 15).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(finalRow, 15).Value

        textRow = textRow + 1

    Next link
```

Thank you!

Comment: Too much code, too little clarity, no data samples...

Comment: Sorry for not having a lot of clarity, I have edited the question by adding some images of what I would like the code to do. I hope this well help.

Comment: @JeannetteLiu: Even with the screenshots, it is really hard to understand your situation and problem! Already your first sentence implies a lot of knowledge about the problem that we do not have! If you want some answer, please rephrase!

Comment: @PeterAlbert, I have added some more explanation and rephrased my question. Is it more helpful? Do I need to provide some more information?

Comment: @JeannetteLiu: Looks more understandable now! I'll try to take a look at it tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the logic in your `Do` and `For Each` loops:

```
Do While Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 1) <> ""

   For Each link In Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 2).Hyperlinks
        textRow = textRow + 1
    Next link

loop 'presumably somewhere after all this...
```

You are trying to do the following (in psuedo code and words):

1. check if the cell is empty
2. if there are links in it, call Display_Stylometric_Scores_URL to report the information
3. move to the next row and go to #1 again

So form your loops like this:

```
textRow = 24
Do While Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 1) <> ""

   'check if there is a link, if so, do your operation on it
     For Each link In Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(textRow, 2).Hyperlinks
        call Display_Stylometric_Scores_URL to report the information
     Next link

    'now we've checked the links in that cell in that row, we can move to the next row
    textRow = textRow + 1
loop 'presumably somewhere after all this...
```

Also make sure you aren't incrementing `textRow` in any of the code you cut off prior to the `loop`.

Comment: I have been playing around with the code but somehow it only works for the first hyperlink. When textRow = textRow + 1 updates to 25, the variable link return "Nothing". It is does not read the url in row 25.

Comment: You need to increment `textRow` after your `Next link` statement.